# Difference between void pointers in C and C++

Tags: c++

Why the following is wrong in C++ (But valid in C)

```
void*p;
char*s;
p=s;
s=p; //this is wrong ,should do s=(char*)p;
```

Why do I need the casting,as `p` now contains address of `char` pointer and `s` is also `char` pointer?

Comment: P is not a char pointer. By assigning the _value_ of `s` to `p`, you are not also assigning the _type_.

Comment: (By the way, your pointers are both uninitialized so their values are indeterminate.)

Comment: What happens if you assign an int pointer to p, and then s=p?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value doesn't matter, the type does. Since `p` is a void pointer and `s` a char pointer,  you have to cast, even if they have the same value. In C it will be ok, `void*` is the generic pointer, but this is incorrect in C++.

By the way, `p` doesn't *contains char pointer*, it's a void pointer and it contains a memory address.

Comment: @Hulk Thanks Hulk, it was just a mistake

Answer (score 17):

That's valid C, but not C++; they are two different languages, even if they do have many features in common.

In C++, there is no implicit conversion from `void*` to a typed pointer, so you need a cast. You should prefer a C++ cast, since they restrict which conversions are allowed and so help to prevent mistakes:

```
s = static_cast<char*>(p);
```

Better still, you should use polymorphic techniques (such as abstract base classes or templates) to avoid the need to use untyped pointers in the first place; but that's rather beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this rule doesn't even have anything to do with pointers. It's just that you can assign values of some type to variables of other types, but not always vice versa. A similar situation would be this:

```
double d = 0.0;
int i = 0;

d = i;    // Totally OK
i = d;    // Warning!
```

So that's just something you have to live with.

Comment: What is "Warning!" supposed to mean? You say that we cannot assign from some types to others, but how does your excerpt evidence that? It compiles and runs just fine - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e53040cdfc520f9 - because just like the converse, `double` has an implicit (if potentially narrowing) conversion to `int`.

Comment: @underscore_d That's what I meant, the potentially narrowing bit. You can enable this warning in g++ and clang with `-Wconversion`. Note that there is no warning for the assignment in the other direction.

Comment: That explains that. I still don't see how this relates to `void *` and the question, though; what am I missing? Implicit pointer conversions are either valid or not; they can't be narrowing-but-allowed. The real answer seems to be that the definition of "valid" changed between C and C++. In contrast, I'm pretty sure the narrowing rules for unrelated numeric types didn't.